# Stacknavigator and Redux connect

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to build a shopping cart into my react-native app

And want to accomplish this with `Redux`

Yet when I try to connect my list to my shopping cart I get the error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props = props')
```

The source of the error being

```
export default  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (createStackNavigator)({
  Products: {
    screen: ProductsScreen,
  },
}, 
{
    initialRouteName: 'Products',
});
```

How come when I add `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)` to my app, it causes it to not function and display the error message?

Comment: Could you be more specific that where you are getting the error ? and the code that is causing it ?

Comment: @SurajMalviya I get the error when adding `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)` to `export default (createStackNavigator)` using it blank doesn't cause any error to accrue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replacing

```
export default  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (createStackNavigator)({
  Products: {
    screen: ProductsScreen,
  },
}, 
{
    initialRouteName: 'Products',
});
```

with

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (ProductsScreen);
```

This still allowed me route to the screen without interfering with the tab navigator